# Array_Search within foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, foreach

I am trying to run an array_search on a foreach loop

```
$i=0;
foreach(findCustomAlerts($customerid) as $key=>$value){ 
   echo "ID of cat : ".$rifdid[$i++] = $value['Catid']."<br>";
   echo "Visits required per day : ".$visitsneeded= $value['Visits required']."<br>";
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($rifdid);
echo "</pre>";

foreach(getTodaysVisits($device_id) as $rfid){
    foreach($rfid as $key=> $read){
    //echo $key."<br>";
    //$i=0;
     if(array_search($key,$rifdid) && $read < $visitsneeded) {
        echo $key." has not visited enough"; 
       // $i++;
   }

}
}
```

The data for the first for each loop is as follows:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [Alertid] => 4 [Catid] => 5609 [Visits required] => 6 ) [1] => Array ( [Alertid] => 5 [Catid] => 23641 [Visits required] => 5 ) )
```

The data for the second foreach is as follows:

```
Array ( [rfid_id] => Array ( [23641] => 1 [5609] => 3 ) )
```

I want to compare the two arrays, and where the rfid id has not reached the required number of visits for that day I need to perform another action.

At the moment when I run the code, it is only picking up that the RFID id 23641 hasnt had enough visits that day, when it should be picking up that both rfids have not been seen enough

This is the current output:
ID of cat : 5609
Visits required per day : 6
ID of cat : 23641
Visits required per day : 5
23641 has not visited enough

It also needs to output
5609 has not visited enough.

Comment: your question is not clear, post all of your input and your expected output.

Comment: Just edited to add additional detals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the following code:

Your first array:

```
$first_arr = Array ( 
        Array ( 
            'Alertid' => 4,
            'Catid' => 5609,
            'Visits_required' => 6 
        ),
        Array ( 
            'Alertid' => 5,
            'Catid' => 23641,
            'Visits_required' => 5
        )
    );
```

Your second array;

```
$second_arr = Array ( 
        'rfid_id' =>  Array ( 
            23641 => 1,
            5609 => 3
        ) 
    );
```

First make a loop in your first array and then make loop in your second array. Match catid and check required visit

```
foreach( $first_arr as $item ){

    foreach( $second_arr as $item2 ){

        foreach( $item2 as $key => $val ){

            if( $key == $item['Catid'] && $val < $item['Visits_required']){
                echo $key .' -- not enough visited <br>....<br>';
            }
            elseif( $key == $item['Catid'] && $val > $item['Visits_required']){
                echo $key . ' -- visited enough <br>....<br>';
            }

        }

    }

}
```

It will output like:

```
5609 -- not enough visited
....
23641 -- not enough visited
....
```

I have added some dots and br to make the output in separate line. You can use the code what needed for you.